# Simulate ArgumentParser object within Python

Tags: python

I have a function (from some external module) that takes an ArgumentParser object (from the `argparse` module) . The function is external and I cannot change its code.

*edit: the function actually takes a `Namespace` object which is the output of the `ArgumentParser.parse_args` function*

I need to call the function from within Python and not from the shell, therefore I need to recreate the ArgumentParser object somehow. Assume I have a dictionary with the same keys as the necessary attributes.

I tried to create an Struct with the same attributes like so:

```py
class Args:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.__dict__.update(kwargs)

cfg = {'attrib': 'abc', 'path': "input/path"}
args = Args(**cfg)

# 1st option
f(args) # Error: argument of type 'Args' is not iterable
# 2nd option
f(cfg) # Error: 'dict' object has no attribute 'attrib'
```

but this fails when trying something like `if 'attrib' in struct` with an error of "argument of type 'Args' is not iterable" (1st option)

On the other hand, if I try to pass a dictionary to the function, I get an error when it tries to access it with `args.attrib` (2nd option)

How can I generate something that will be compatible with ArgumentParser?

Comment: Do you need an `ArgumentParser`, or a *parsed argument* result‽

Comment: I need the equivalent of a parsed result, without having any arguments from the shell

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.Namespace — You can probably just instantiate one of those and assign arbitrary properties to it.

Comment: It was even easier than that, I just used `args = parser.parse_args(['--attrib', 'abc'])` from the link you sent. Thanks!

Comment: So your question is inaccurate. The function doesn't take an `ArgumentParser` object but a `Namespace` object...

Comment: @Tomerikoo Correct, I edited the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ArgumentParser.parse_args` just returns an `argparse.Namespace` object with arbitrary attributes. To imitate that, just instantiate that yourself and set your attributes on it:

```
import argparse

args = argparse.Namespace()
args.attrib = 'abc'
args.path = 'input/path'

f(args)
```

To convert an existing dict to such a `Namespace` object, something like this'll do:

```
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> reduce(lambda n, i: setattr(n, *i) or n, cfg.items(), argparse.Namespace())
Namespace(attrib='abc', path='input/path')
```

Or, it even appears to support constructor arguments:

```
args = argparse.Namespace(**cfg)
```